# Anonymous access and Audience Targeting

Tags: audience-targeting

We've turned on Anonymous Access and our Pages library has 'Audience Targeting' turned on, the trouble now is, that for pages to be seen by anonymous users, I have to go into each page and set value for each page to 'All site visitors'.

This is extremely laborious, I can't seen to find a 'bulk change' option in the web interface, is this really how it supposed to work, none of the doco I can find seems to remark this is needed.

Comment: This turned out to be something odd with our SP installation, as other environments didn't require this audience targeting to be done with Anonymous access.

Answer (score 1):

By turning on audience targeting you are essentially saying that the contents of this pages library are going to be targeted at specific users/groups.

If your expecting most people to be accessing the site via anonymous access then how can you target any individual users or groups?  So what is the benefit to having audience targeting turned on?

If there is some business requirement for this then you could possibly write an event receiver to attach to the pages library which automatically set the audience targeting column to 'All Site Visitors', but this seems like an odd requirement.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I could image is writing a small tool iterating all site collections, websites and lits and setting the value for you.